# Toggling the color of a button's drawable and text in java

Tags: java, android, button

I need a Button or TextView that changes the color of its CompoundDrawable (Top) and Text when it is clicked to show whether or not is on.

1. It needs to be either a Button or TextView
2. There can only be 1 drawable resource per button
3. The Text color needs to change
4. DrawableTop color need to change, NOT BE REPLACED WITH A DIFFERENT DRAWABLE
5. The background of the view needs to remain transparent
6. The state of the button needs to be saved

I tried different things, but I think my best shot is to create a new Java file which extends Button or TextView. I was thinking something like this:

```
public class CustomButton extends android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton {

    int colorOn;
    int colorOff;
    boolean isOn = false;

    public CustomButton(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }

    private void onButtonClicked(){

        if(isOn){
            setCompoundDrawablesColors(colorOn);
            setTextColor(colorOn);
        } else {

            setCompoundDrawablesColors(colorOff);
            setTextColor(colorOff);
        }

        isOn = !isOn;
    }
}
```

My questions are:

- Where do I insert onButtonClicked? onTouchEvent? onPressed? onFocused? Implement an OnClickListener?
- How do I change the color of the Drawable so it updates UI immediately? I know changing the color is done with setCompoundDrawablesTint(color, mode). Does that update the UI asap? I haven't been able to get it to work.
- How do I do this without any XML code?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, you can customize the view to draw their own, you can dispatchTouchEvent (MotionEvent event) to listen to the key state call OnClickListener, this will be easier to achieve.

Comment: Customizing the view is exactly what I am looking to do. I have no clue about how I should tackle the problem. What do you mean by dispatch TouchEvent? And how would I go about doing that?

Comment: I mean that the customization of a view inherits View instead of android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton, so you can define your own click-to-touch time processing logic